# using VPN IP Address

Tags: vpn, ip-address, fortinet

I use FotreClient to VPN to my company
Previously I was getting same IP address as i am in the company

after few changes to the server and upgrading ForteClient now when I VPN to the company I still keep my own IP address although I can access everything on the company's network.
but the IP address stays mine.

I want to get the company IP address especially when I am browsing the internet.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Either disallow split tunneling on the server end of things, or reconfigure your client to create a default route that points to the gateway on the other end of the VPN.

Comment: how to reconfigure my client ?

Comment: @asmgx you'll need to talk with your IT department about that.